# How to change the configuration of email alert schedule for monitoring tool

Tags: nagios

I use Nagios to monitoring the server status , if I would like to change the email alert schedule for example , now it will send email alert in each hour , I would like to change every 3 hour or once per day , could which file that I should change ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Search your config files for notification_interval.